# Check if shutdown schedule is active and when it is

Tags: shutdown, 17.10, schedule

I have been trying to determine if a shutdown has been scheduled in my system (Ubuntu 17.10). If I input via terminal "shutdown 100", it confirms that system will shut down at a time. But later on, how can I check which time it was if I have that terminal close already.

I found several solutions but none of them works:

```
ps -ef | grep shutdown
```

It shows shutdown all the time, even if shutdown has been cancelled.

```
systemctl status systemd-shutdownd.service
```

It seems it does not work anymore

```
cat /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled
```

It returns the same either if there is shutdown pending or not.

Comment: How did you schedule the shut-down or how do you presume the shut-down was scheduled?

Comment: Through terminal. "shutdown 10". I cancel it with "shutdown -c".

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

A very simple solution:

```
date -d @`cat /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled | head -n 1 | cut -c6-15`
```

Comment: Just retested on focal (20.04) server. Works perfectly fine. (Fabian Jakobs solution is not for server installations 'cause it requires a Desktop / GUI installed.) The use case for the question occurs to be server rather than desktop. Thank you.
Unfortunately not marked as correct (yet).

Answer (score 6):

I've had success using

```
$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager ScheduledShutdown
```

For example:

```
$ sudo shutdown -h +30                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Shutdown scheduled for Wed 2018-10-10 09:33:44 UTC, use 'shutdown -c' to cancel.
$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager ScheduledShutdown
(st) "poweroff" 1539164024057786
$ sudo shutdown -c
$ busctl get-property org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager ScheduledShutdown
(st) "" 0
```